# Difference between kk and HH in date formatting java

Tags: java, datetime, date-format, simpledateformat

I'm pretty new to java and am trying to format a time using 24 hour format. I've come across two ways of formatting the hour - HH and kk:

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
SimpleDateFormat format2 new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(format1.format(date));
System.out.println(format2.format(date));
```

These both produce something like 11:21. What's the difference between them? Am I missing something?

Comment: What part of [the documentaion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is confusing you?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The two formats essentially do the same thing but differ in how they handle `midnight`. `kk` will format `midnight` to `24:00` whereas `HH` will format to `00:00`. The hours in a day in `k` are `1-24` and in `H` are `0-23`

It's always worth checking the [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) as it generally provides very useful explanations as well as examples of uses.

Answer (score 6):

try this to see the difference

```
    SimpleDateFormat format1 =  new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
    Date date = new GregorianCalendar(2001, 0, 1, 0, 0 , 0 ).getTime();
    System.out.println(format1.format(date));
    System.out.println(format2.format(date));
```

output

```
00:00
24:00
```